# Gradle as non root

Tags: gradle, kubernetes, kubernetes-security, jib

Could you please let me know how to run a `gradle` image (pulled from `docker` repository), with `jib` plugin and running as non-`root` user in `Kubernetes pod`?

I have build a `gradle` image using `Gradle 4.6`.

I’m using this image in my `Kubernetes pod`.

When I run the image as user - `root`, the `gradle` build is successful.

When I run the image as non-`root` user (because of `pod RBAC` enablement),  the build fails as `gradle` is unable to create `/.gradle` directory and there are no sufficient privileges and getting the below error.

> Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.

Is there any way to grant the non-`root` user passed via `securityContext` to perform the build successfully using the `gradle` image?

Is there a better way to resolve the issue without changing the directory permission to `777` .

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Check if `/.gradle` directory is already created by `root`

E.g. using `stat` command. You might see that current user doesn't have enough permissions to work with it:

```
$ stat ~/.gradle | grep Uid
> Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

If so, change owner of the directory:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.gradle
```

Where

- `sudo chown -R` does recursive owner update
- `$USER` contains current username

Comment: Thanks! Could you please let me know whether  there is any other better option as unable to change the gradle image? Moreover, I want any non-root user to run the pod.

Comment: If you run image on clear host, or with other user (that doesn't have `.gradle` directory yet) - it will run correctly, without issues. `gradle` is designed in user, non-`root` mode

Comment: Also, you might try to remove `.gradle` directory at all and try again.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have access to the host as running the command from my local machine. Is there any way to delete the .gradle directory. Also, since, I have --rerun-tasks in my gradle command, won't it start from beginning?  Other way, I can change the location of the install. Please let me know if you know of any better option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the official [Gradle](https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle) image on Docker Hub.

The `gradle:4.6` image is designed and meant to be run as user `gradle` (UID 1000).

```
$ docker inspect gradle:4.6 --format '{{.Config.User}}'
gradle
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint id gradle:4.6
uid=1000(gradle) gid=1000(gradle) groups=1000(gradle)
```

Therefore, it only works when running the image as user `root` (UID 0) or `gradle` (UID 1000).

```
# These all work.
$ docker run --rm --user 0 gradle:4.6
$ docker run --rm --user root gradle:4.6
$ docker run --rm --user 1000 gradle:4.6
$ docker run --rm --user gradle gradle:4.6

# However, this doesn't work.
$ docker run --rm --user 1234 gradle:4.6

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Therefore, you just need to make sure that you run the container as user `1000` or `gradle` (on whatever container runtime environment you use). And because the image `gradle:4.6` is configured to run as `1000`, when you build a new image based on `gradle:4.6`, it should run OK on almost all container runtime platforms (unless you override the configured user at the platform level).

---

(Now, the following assumes that you are using Jib to build another Gradle-like image based on `gradle:4.6` and that you are using this new Gradle-like image on Kubernetes. That is, the following doesn't apply if you are using Jib to containerize a normal application image inside `gradle:4.6`.)

However, there is a [bug in Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2421) that does not inherit the configured user from the base image. The bug will be fixed in the next 2.3.0 release. In the meantime, you can explicitly tell Jib to configure the user in the built image. In `build.gradle`, set

```
jib.container.user = 'gradle:gradle'
```

or if you prefer numeric UID and GID,

```
jib.container.user = '1000:1000'
```

. Or you can set the system property on the command-line:

```
./gradlew -Djib.container.user='gradle:gradle' ... jib
```

Another option is to set the correct user on the Kubernetes side. For example, within `securityContext`, you can set [`runAsUser: 1000` and `runAsGroup: 1000`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod).

Finally, although `gradle:4.6` is built to run as user `gradle` (UID 1000), I see that recently they have reverted this decision. Now `gradle:latest` is configured to run as `root`.

```
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint id gradle
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Thanks Much for the very detailed explanation!  I tried using user -1000 in my Kubernetes SecurityContext and it didn't help. The reason is I'm mounting a project volume to copy the project from my Git repository and running the gradle(jib) image. Since, this volume mount is setup before Container is created, the permission for my /project (mount directory) is 755 . User-root has full permission and everything works fine with user-root. I'm trying to use InitContainer and change the /project permission to 775 and run as user - 1000.  Please let me know if there is any better solution.

Comment: Hi Chanseok, I tried with securityContext: runAsUser: 1000 and runAsGroup: 1000 in Kubernetes Pod and also had the user set to 1000 ( and tried with user - gradle as well) in the gradle command inside the pod which uses Gradle 4.6 image (from docker hub and jib plugin initialized in build.gradle file) , the build fails. However, the build is successful when I use securityContext: runAsUser: 0. Could you please let me know whether this is a bug in gradle 4.6 and Jib 4.0.4? Also, could you let me know whether there is any workaround for this issue? Your help will be useful . Thanks!

Comment: @testbgtestbg seems like I misunderstood your environment. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2438#issuecomment-621257197